# When I try stack setup, ghc gives a sanity-check error and will not compile

Tags: haskell-stack

I had a working stack project.  After experimenting with cabal-install, when I tried to use stack again I had errors.  So in trying to restore my system, I deleted the global .cabal file, not realizing that stack uses it.  When on run stack setup on my project I get the following:

```
Downloaded lts-13.23 build plan.    
Preparing to install GHC to an isolated location.
This will not interfere with any system-level installation.
Downloaded ghc-8.6.5.                                      
Installed GHC.                                                                 
The GHC located at /home/bruce/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.6.5/bin/ghc failed to compile a sanity check. Please see:

    http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/install_and_upgrade/

for more information. Exception was:
Received ExitFailure 1 when running
Raw command: /home/bruce/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.6.5/bin/ghc /tmp/stack-sanity-check14961/Main.hs -no-user-package-db
Run from: /tmp/stack-sanity-check14961/
Standard error:

Loaded package environment from /home/bruce/.ghc/x86_64-linux-8.6.5/environments/default
ghc: can't find a package database at /home/bruce/.cabal/store/ghc-8.6.5/package.db
```

How can return to a working stack installation?